# How to make a specific leave event for each card in Dulst?

Tags: rules

We want to make a effect that trigger a customized leaveBoard event, for example, when a card with ciid=137 leaves board, we want a leave137 event triggered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new card in your Rule cards, in effect build, click Code and copy & paste the code below

```
- effectName: cards
  ruleTrigger:
    primary: start
    player: each player
  action:
    primary: trigger on event
    event:
      primary: leavesBoard
  target:
    primary: card
    criteria:
      from: board
      player: owner
- effectName: card
  action:
    primary: each
  target:
    primary: card
    criteria:
      passing: cards
  effectComplete:
    primary: nothing
- effectName: leaveEvent
  action:
    primary: assign variable
  target:
    primary: value
    value: leave$ciid
  effectComplete:
    primary: trigger next effect
- action:
    primary: trigger event
    event:
      primary: $leaveEvent
  target:
    primary: game
  effectComplete:
    primary: nothing
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.